# zgetrf routine is very slow with gfortran 9.3

Tags: performance, compiler-errors, g++, gfortran, blitz++

I have a c++ code (compiled with g++) that creates and fills a blitz++ matrix filled with complex double values (I call it lseMatrix). The matrix is then inverted with a zgetrf fortran routine as

> zgetrf_(&n, &n, &((*lseMatrix)(0, 0)), &n, &(iPiv(0)), &info)

I have my old machine (under Ubuntu 16.04, single processor) that has g++ and gfortran (versions 5.4) and lapack/blas (v. 3.6.0-2ubuntu2) installed. The code runs perfectly fine there and it takes about 10 mins to invert relatively large matrix with zgetrf. However, when I run the code with my new machine (under Ubuntu 20.04, two paired processors) having the newest versions of g++ and gfotran (v. 9.3) and the latest lapack/blas (3.9.0-1build1), the inversion operation takes 5 hours.

The following tests are already made:

1. Running the code on old and new machines without compilation optimisation flags. Result: the performance does not change.
2. Trying to create a static library with a -static flag at the linking stage on the old machine and running the produced .exe file on the new machine. This partially solves the problem. The performance speed is the same on two machines, but the program can crush sometimes unexpectedly.

Advices on possible solutions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. It would be very helpful to show us a small test program that we could compime, run and see if it is fast or small.  You should probably test the performance of the subroutine for a larger range of matrix sizes yourself anyway. See also [mcve]. Be aware that to achieve top performance, you should use some high-prrormance BLAS implementation, such as OpenBLAS, GotoBLAS, ATLAS or MKL. Was your old machine BLAS threaded or not?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Vladimir,

The problem is solved. I installed BLAS on the new server, but did not notice that the program was actually linked with the OpenBLAS on my old server. Installing OpenBLAS completely solved the problem. It appears to be an interesting point, that I can not see during the compilation whether I link libraries with BLAS or OpenBLAS.